# PySpark Suggestion on how to organize RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm a Spark noobie and I'm trying to test something out on Spark and see if there are any performance boosts for the size of data that I'm using.

Each object in my rdd contains a time, id, and position.

I want to compare the positions of groups with same times containing the same id. So, I would first run the following to get grouped by id

```
grouped_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x.id, [x])).groupByKey()
```

I would then like to break this into the time of each object.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want both `id` and `time` as key, just put them both into key part, rather than first group by id, then group by time separately.

```
m = sc.parallelize([(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(2,3,5)])
n = m.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2]))
```

Secondly, [Avoid GroupByKey](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) which performs bad and use `combineByKey` or `reduceByKey` if possible.

Comment: Great thank you for the response. How would I group by both `id` and `time`? `grouped_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: ((x.id, x.time), [x]))`?

Comment: @JeffreyKamei, see edit above, the `n` in the answer can then be called with `combineByKey` or `reduceByKey` with combined key.