# PySpark Create Multi Indexed Paired RDD with function

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

A little while ago I asked a question about organizing and structuring an RDD with a multiple keys. See [PySpark Suggestion on how to organize RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338185/pyspark-suggestion-on-how-to-organize-rdd/30338727?noredirect=1#comment48863802_30338727)

Each object in my current rdd contains a `start_time`, `end_time`, `id`, and `position`.

I want to group the objects by `id` and `time`. I will group two or more objects together if they have both the same `id` or any overlapping times.

The logic for finding the overlap is pretty easy:

```
if x1.start_time > x2.start_time and x1.start_time < x2.end_time
if x2.start_time > x1.start_time and x2.start_time < x2.end_time
```

I just don't quite get how to go about creating a paired RDD with this logic though.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is with join on the id and then filter the result (if there aren't too many with the same id). To do this I'd start by mapping the RDDs to (id, record) and then doing the join.

Comment: thank you for your response! Unfortunately, there are a good amount of objects that have the same id. One question - did you mean "To do this I'd start by mapping the RDDs to (id, record) and then doing the **filter**"?

Comment: Well we can't do a filter before the join since your filter condition depends on looking at the times stamps. If you have a lot of objects with the same idea such that the cross product of objects with the same id is too large then I think the next most reasonable approach is doing cogroup and then doing a flat map with your join logic.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so are you suggesting that I cogroup like this: `rdd.map(lambda x: (x.id, (x.startTime(), x.endTime(), [x])))`?

Comment: That would be the start yah.